# Retornar vários arrays utilizando um buffer sem sobrecarregar a memória

Tags: php, mysql, sql, memória

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que, em um relatório, preciso imprimir algo em torno de 50.000 linhas. Quando tendo executar o SELECT ocorre o erro:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 24 bytes) in
>   C:\wamp\www\simplaFramework\System\Framework\Model.class.class.php on
>   line 884.

O resultado da consulta a seguir está sendo salvo em um `array` pois vou tratá-lo depois:

```
        $data = array();
        $count = 0;
        while ($row = $q->fetch($pdo_fetch)) {                     
            $data[] = $row;                    
            ++$count;
        }
```

A minha ideia era dividir o resultado em 2 ou mais arrays sempre que chegar a uma quantidade X de uso de memória.
Por exemplo: quando o uso aproximar de 128mb (obtenho este valor com `memory_get_usage()`) divido o resultado em 2 ou mais arrays e retorno o resultado.

Mas como posso fazer isso? Devo utilizar um Buffer?

Comment: Já tento usar `fetchAll()` no lugar de `fetch()` ? Se não nenhuma condição para incrementar `$count`, use função `count()` passando como argumento o array de `fetchAll()`.

Comment: O problema não está no modo como recupero os dados no banco e sim ao armazenar os dado na variável: `$data[] = $row;`. Ela excede o tamanho em memória do PHP (128M), e preciso passar os dados para outra função antes de imprimir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema acontece porque normalmente o PHP usa buffered queries. Isso significa que o PHP recebe todas as linhas de resultado antes de retornar a chamada para consultas.

Para resolver o problema você deve usar [unbuffered queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php). Assim o PHP retorna uma linha resultado de cada vez para a aplicação processar sem ficar armazenando tudo primeiro em memória.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

É preciso ter alguns cuidados porque usando unbuffered queries, isso implica deixar uma transação em aberto enquanto não retornar todos resultados. Isso significa que poderá bloquear o retardar o acesso às tabelas por outras consultas paralelas.

Outra consequência é que em alguns tipos de bancos de dados pode não dar para executar outra consulta enquanto não retornar todos resultados.

Uma solução alternativa para evitar esses problemas usar unbuffered queries e salvar os resultados para um arquivo local, por exemplo em formato CSV, com as linhas de resultados até ao fim, e depois volta a ler o arquivo para processar os resultados um a um, evitando deixar a transação em aberto e liberando a conexão para executar outras consultas durante o processamento dos resultados.

Comment: Obrigado @mlemos, a sua resposta esclareceu exatamente as minhas dúvidas, apesar das demais respostas terem sido satisfatórias.

Answer (score 3):

Implemente uma paginação nas queries, ou seja, colete o resultset de 1000 em 1000 linhas (por exemplo) usando a cláusula `LIMIT` do MySQL.

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 0, 1000

SELECT ... LIMIT 1000, 1000

SELECT ... LIMIT 2000, 1000
```

(etc.)

No meu caso, eu executaria uma primeira query só para contar o total de linhas e, em seguida, dividiria esse total pelo número de resultados por query. Daí em seguida é só falar o que sugeri acima :)

Answer (score 3):

Não entendo muito sobre buffers no PHP, mas creio que o correto neste caso seria "soltar" o que está armazenado na array, e depois ir buscar o restante.

Acho que uma opção interessante seria o uso de ajax neste caso, uma vez que você pode ir até o servidor, buscar uma quantidade de dados que você limitar, imprimir na tela e, caso não tenha terminado a requisição completamente, retornar por ajax ao servidor e pegar mais uma quantidade de dados.

Para isso você usaria apenas uma flag, indicando se o processamento no servidor chegou ao fim ou não. Caso não tenha chegado você pede para o ajax ir até o servidor novamente e continuar da onde você parou.

Pode até mesmo usar a dica que o amigo @rodrigorigotti, dividindo o resultado da query em pedaços e depois retornando de onde parou.

Answer (score 3):

Se puder quebrar os registros utilize paginação `limit/off set` como citado pelo @rodrigorigotti

caso contrario tente uma das seguintes abordagens.

**Possiveis soluções**

**Mais rápida:**

Aumentar o limite de memória do script (utilizar em casos urgentes), coloque esse código no inicio do script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

**FetchAll**

Mudar o código para utilizar fetchAll isso elimina o `for` as N atribuições. Lembre que é necessario usar preparedStaments.

```
$registros = $q->fetchAll();
$total = count($registros);
```

Comment: Agora entendi o que você quis dizer. Quando devo usar o fetchAll e o fetch?

Comment: A diferença entre eles é que `fetch()` retorna apenas um registro equanto `fetchAll()` retorna todos de uma vez só.